# Use Configuration values in a File Pipe Validator with NestJS

Tags: validation, nestjs, pipe

I have a validation pipe for upload files that works.

```
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
public async UploadTimeSheetFile(
    @UploadedFile(
        new ParseFilePipe({
            validators: [
                new MaxFileSizeValidator({ maxSize: 100000 }), // maxSize is in bytes

                new EndOfWeekValidator({
                    EndOfWeekDayNumber: 6,
                } as EndOfWeekValidatorOptions),
```

Without worrying about the implementation details, creating these settings with static values works.  However, I want to be able to use these from my configuration service.  However, if I try to use a variable (from the constructor accessing the configuration service) I get an error.

```
private ValidationConfig_: DateValidatorOptions;

constructor(
    private readonly AppConfig_: ConfigurationService
) {
    this.ValidationConfig_.EndOfWeekDayNumber = this.AppConfig_.GetEndOfWeekDay;
}
```

I then try to use this value:

```
new EndOfWeekValidator({
    EndOfWeekDayNumber: this.Configuration.EndOfWeekDayNumber
} as EndOfWeekValidatorOptions),
```

And an error is returned `Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)`

Is there a way to set the values dynamically from my configuration, versus having to hard code values in the NestJS File Pipe custom validators?

Comment: It is not possible in this case, since `@UploadedFile` is a parameter decorator, and it will be called once the class is defined, not being initialized.